# MySQL unique clustered constraint not constraining as expected

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm creating a table with:

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
 id     INT       AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 name   CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 year   INT       NOT NULL,
 inyear CHAR(10), 
 CONSTRAINT UNIQUE CLUSTERED (name, year, inyear)
);
```

(this is jdbc SQL)

Which creates a MySQL table with a `clustered` index, "index kind" is "unique", and spans the three clustered columns:

[mysql screen http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/930/mysqlscreenshot.th.jpg](http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/930/mysqlscreenshot.th.jpg)
[full size](http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/930/mysqlscreenshot.jpg)

However, once I dump my data (without exceptions thrown), I see that the uniqueness constraint has failed:

```
SELECT * FROM movies
WHERE name = 'Flawless' AND year = 2007 AND inyear IS NULL;
```

gives:

```
id,     name,       year, inyear
162169, 'Flawless', 2007, NULL
162170, 'Flawless', 2007, NULL
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your choice of unique composite key index name "CLUSTERED" is confusing. Are you aware of what a clustered index is ? If you're using innodb then every primary key you define for a table is a clustered index. You can only have one clustered index per innodb table as a clustered index sorts and stores the data rows in the table based on the index key values. Therefore only one clustered index can be created on each table because the data rows themselves can only be sorted in one order.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not consider NULL values as equal; hence, why the unique constraint appears to not be working.  To get around this, you can add a computed column to the table which is defined as:

```
nullCatch as (case when inyear is null then '-1' else inyear)
```

Substitute this column in for 'inyear' in the constraint:

```
 CONSTRAINT UNIQUE CLUSTERED (name, year, nullCatch)
```