# IF NOT EXISTS in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have tow tables concept_access and concept_access_log. I want to create a trigger that works every time something is deleted from concept_access, check if there is similar record in log table and if not, inserts new one before it is deleted from concept_access.

I modified trigger and now it looks like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_delete_concept_access;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete_concept_access
    BEFORE DELETE ON `concept_access` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM concept_access_log WHERE map=OLD.map 
                          AND accesstype=OLD.accesstype AND startdate=OLD.startdate AND stopdate=OLD.stopdate) IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO concept_access_log (map, accesstype, startdate, stopdate)
            VALUES (OLD.map, OLD.accesstype, OLD.startdate, OLD.stopdate);
        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample data in concept_access before delete:

```
map accesstype  startdate   stopdate
1   public      NULL        NULL    
1   loggedin    2011-05-11  NULL    
1   friends     NULL        NULL
```

Log table already has first 2 rows. And they are exactly the same as in concept_access. When I delete first row from concept_access table, I get this in log table:

```
map accesstype  startdate   stopdate
1   public      NULL        NULL    
1   loggedin    2011-05-11  NULL    
1   friends     NULL        NULL    
1   public      NULL        NULL
```

While it is not supposed to insert anything because (1,public,null,null) already exists there.

This table has no primary key. I was not creating structure, so don't ask me why. Changing it will ruin a lot of already existing functionality. I just need to keep log of what was removed from table `concept_access` and store it in log without duplicates.

I would really appreciate, if anyone can figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: OK, I figured out what the problem is, but still can't find proper solution. Some fields can be NULL and, in case OLD value equals null, doing something like `accesstype=OLD.accesstype` won't work. I tried to change it to `(accesstype=OLD.accesstype OR OLD.accesstype IS NULL)`, but still no luck...

Comment: can you show us the entire modified trigger, too, as well as sample data in "concept_access" and the records in the log table before and after you delete?

Comment: @pilcrow: Updates are in the body of the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_delete_concept_access;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete_concept_access
    BEFORE DELETE ON `concept_access` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM concept_access_log WHERE map=OLD.map 
                          AND accesstype=OLD.accesstype AND startdate=OLD.startdate AND stopdate=OLD.stopdate) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO concept_access_log (map, accesstype, startdate, stopdate)
            VALUES (OLD.map, OLD.accesstype, OLD.startdate, OLD.stopdate);
        END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I am not using `not exists`, just test if the match count greater than 0

your code runs well on my machine, what's your MySQL version?

```
mysql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.56-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Jull, are you using the _exact_ trigger that Neo posted?  In my testing, this answer doesn't handle NULLs correctly, just as you commented in response to your own question above...

Comment: not exactly the same, I added conditions like `(accesstype=OLD.accesstype OR OLD.accesstype IS NULL)`. But overall thing with `Count(*) = 0` now works for me.

Comment: @Jull, those conditions are not quite correct.  Deleted record (1, 'foo', NULL, NULL) will appear to match logged record (1, NULL, NULL, NULL).  See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @pilcrow, hmmm... I haven't seen that problem. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Er, sorry -- swap "deleted" and "logged"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
... WHERE map = OLD.map ...

--  map   OLD.map  bool
--  ---   -------  ----
--  'a'    'a'     TRUE
--  'a'    'b'     FALSE
--  'a'    NULL    FALSE
--  NULL   'b'     FALSE
--  NULL   NULL    FALSE  <-- Undesired! We want this to be TRUE
```

try `<=>`, which is [MySQL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134368/is-is-distinct-from-a-real-mysql-operator) to the SQL standard [`IS (NOT) DISTINCT FROM` predicate](https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from):

```
... WHERE map <=> OLD.map ...
--  TRUE when both have the same non-NULL value or when both are NULL
--  Equivalents:
--    WHERE (map = OLD.map OR (map IS NULL AND OLD.map IS NULL))
--    WHERE (map = OLD.map OR COALESCE(map, OLD.map) IS NULL)
```

Comment: I think that the second option won't work. I discovered that MySQL does not see NULL values as equal. Therefore, the unique constraint will not work for rows with NULL values. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520894/mysql-unique-clustered-constraint-not-constraining-as-expected)