# Is 'IS DISTINCT FROM' a real MySQL operator?

Tags: mysql, logical-operators

In one book I see this syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM inw WHERE id IS DISTINCT FROM 4;
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT FROM 4' at line 1

It's an alternative for:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM inw WHERE id is null OR id <> 4;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
|    3 |
+------+
```

Is 'IS DISTINCT FROM' a real MySQL operator?

Comment: It's [postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from) syntax, not mysql.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`is distinct from` is defined in the SQL:2003 standard and is a null-safe operator to compare two values.

MySQL supports a ["null safe equals" operator: `<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). If that is negated, you get the same behaviour. (the `<=>` corresponds to `is not distinct from`)

```
SELECT * 
FROM inw 
WHERE not id <=> 4;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0abf2a/3

Comment: `WHERE id <=> 4` doesn't seem to match `WHERE id IS NULL OR  id<>4`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: yes, you are right. I forgot the `NOT`