# Add random unique reference to Rails Friendly_id vanity URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have a *Product* model that contains the product name and a unique reference randomly generated before the product creation. I want to use both to generate a frindly_id URL. Here is my try:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  name        :string           not null
#  slug        :string
#  reference   :string
#
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  before_create :generate_unique_reference
  friendly_id :friendly_id_syntax, use: :slugged

  def generate_unique_reference
    self.reference = SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase
  end

  def friendly_id_syntax
    [
      [:name, :reference]
    ]
  end
end
```

This generates a vanity URL that only contains the product name (without the product reference). Seems the slug generation is done when the *reference* attribute is still *nil*. I have the same result when I put the `friendly_id :friendly_id_syntax, use: :slugged` before the `before_create`.

Have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/8069fc9959215e5f4872927928b3b7a95e9beacd/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L226):

> FriendlyId uses a before_validation callback to generate and set the
>   slug...

`before_validation` runs before `before_create`. So to fix it, change the `before_create` to `before_validation`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  before_validation :generate_unique_reference, on: :create
  friendly_id :friendly_id_syntax, use: :slugged

  def generate_unique_reference
    self.reference = SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase
  end

  def friendly_id_syntax
    [
      [:name, :reference]
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to possibly use [`slug_candidates`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50) (although I don't think it will provide the exact functionality you want):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

   def reference
      SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase
   end

   private

   def slug_candidates
      [
        [:name, :reference]
      ]
   end
end
```

Okay, I just realized it's exactly what you've done already. I'll still post the answer in case anyone wants to see another interpretation of the question; I'll delete if necessary.

---

Something else you *may* wish to consider is implementing a [`uuid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) in your database:

> A universally unique identifier (UUID) is an identifier standard used in software construction. A UUID is simply a 128-bit value. The meaning of each bit is defined by any of several variants.

Most people will rip me apart for even suggesting this; you have to replace your `id` primary key with a string like: `de305d54-75b4-431b-adb2-eb6b9e546014`

We do it with some of our stuff:

[image]

There are several benefits to this, including that you can reference individual objects regardless of where they're stored and - as you're finding - the ability to use the `uuid` in something like a slug.

You can take this as you want; I'd implement a `uuid` and then make `friendly_id` update `after_create`:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

   after_create :set_new_friendly_id

   private

   def slug_candidates
      [
        [:name, :uuid]
      ]
   end

   def set_new_friendly_id
      self.save #-> I know a double SQL call, but only way to get UUID
   end

   def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      uuid.present? #-> only updates if uuid is present
   end
end
```

To get the `uuid` working, you have to use either the [`uuid()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) function in MYSQL, or the [`uuid_generate_v4`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html) function in PGSQL:

```
# db/schama.rb
create_table "nodes", force: :cascade, id: false do |t|
    t.string   "uuid",        limit: 255, default: (Rails.env.staging? ? "uuid_generate_v4();" : 0), null: false
    t.string   "type",        limit: 255
    t.string   "slug",        limit: 255
    t.string   "title",       limit: 255
    t.text     "value",       limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end

  execute "ALTER TABLE nodes ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);"
  if Rails.env.staging? #-> Heroku PGSQL
    execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\"")
  else
    execute("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_nodes;") #http://stackoverflow.com/a/5945220/1143732
    execute("CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_nodes BEFORE INSERT ON nodes FOR EACH ROW SET new.uuid = uuid();")
  end
```

Whilst this takes the `UUID` generation out of the application logic, it means you can only use the UUID *after* you've created a record. This is why it may be sketchy to use it with `friendly_id`; but may end up providing you with functionality you wanted.